# Yet another shell in C

Tags: beginner, c, strings, shell, child-process

I wrote this [shell](https://github.com/xorz57/shell) in C about a semester ago for a university assignment on operating systems. Even though I got a score of 10/10 in this assignment, I doubt it deserved it -

- The pipeline implementation could be written better.
- There were some cases (1%) where I got the pipeline to stuck while bash did not.
- Maybe some functions could be broken down into smaller/simpler ones.
- The debug messages (although they were optional) could be written in a log file.

We were not allowed to split the source code into separate files

Here is the source code for it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

struct subcommand_t {
    char **argument; // Array of arguments
    size_t size;     // Number of arguments
};

struct command_t {
    struct subcommand_t *subcommand; // Array of subcommands.
    size_t size;                     // Number of subcommands.
};

struct line_t {
    struct command_t *command; // Array of commands.
    size_t size;               // Number of commands.
};

void prompt(char *prompt) {
    #ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "[PROMPT] Displaying prompt\n");
    #endif
    fprintf(stdout, "%s ", prompt);
}

char *reader(size_t size){
    char *buffer;
    #ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "[READER] Allocating memory for buffer [size: %zu]\n", size);
    #endif
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    if (buffer == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    #ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "[READER] Reading to buffer\n");
    #endif
    int character;
    size_t length = 0;
    while (EOF != (character = fgetc(stdin)) && character != '\n') {
        buffer[length++] = (char) character;
        if (length == size) {
            #ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "[READER] Reallocating memory for buffer [size: %zu]\n", size);
            #endif
            buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(char) * (size += 32));
            if (buffer == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    #ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "[READER] Setting the NULL terminator for buffer\n");
    #endif
    buffer[length++] = '\0';
    return realloc(buffer, sizeof(char) * length);
}

void executor(struct line_t line) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size; ++i) {
        #ifdef DEBUG
        fprintf(stderr, "[EXECUTOR] Executing line.command[%zu]\n", i);
        #endif
        int previous;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < line.command[i].size; ++j) {
            #ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "[EXECUTOR] Executing line.command[%zu].subcommand[%zu]\n", i, j);
            #endif
            int p[2];
            pipe(p);
            if (line.command[i].subcommand[j].size != 0) {
                if (strcmp(line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument[0], "exit") == 0) {
                    #ifdef DEBUG
                    fprintf(stderr, "[EXECUTOR] Exiting shell\n");
                    #endif
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                } else if (strcmp(line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument[0], "cd") == 0) {
                    #ifdef DEBUG
                    fprintf(stderr, "[EXECUTOR] Changing directory to %s\n", line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument[1]);
                    #endif
                    chdir(line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument[1]);
                } else {
                    switch(fork()) {
                        case -1:
                            #ifdef DEBUG
                            fprintf(stderr, "[EXECUTOR] Failed to fork a child process\n");
                            #endif
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        case  0:
                            #ifdef DEBUG
                            fprintf(stderr, "[EXECUTOR] Running on a child process [pid: %d]\n", getpid());
                            #endif
                            if (j == 0) {
                                dup2(0, STDIN_FILENO);
                            } else {
                                dup2(previous, STDIN_FILENO);
                            }
                            close(p[0]);
                            if (j+1 < line.command[i].size) {
                                dup2(p[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
                            }
                            close(p[0]);
                            execvp(line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument[0], line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument);
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        default:
                            #ifdef DEBUG
                            fprintf(stderr, "[EXECUTOR] Running on the parent process [%d]\n", getpid());
                            #endif
                            previous=p[0];
                            close(p[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #ifdef DEBUG
        fprintf(stderr, "[EXECUTOR] Waiting for any terminated child processes\n");
        #endif
        while(wait(NULL) > 0) {
            #ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "[EXECUTOR] Found a terminated child process\n");
            #endif
        }
    }
}

struct line_t parser(char *buffer, char *del1, char *del2, char *del3) {
    size_t i, j, k;
    char *str1, *str2, *str3;
    char *token1, *token2, *token3;
    char *saveptr1, *saveptr2, *saveptr3;

    struct line_t line;
    line.size=0;
    line.command=NULL;
    for (i = 0, str1 = buffer ;; i++, str1 = NULL) {
        token1 = strtok_r(str1, del1, &saveptr1);
        if (token1 == NULL) break;
        line.size++;
        if (i == 0) {
            #ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "[PARSER] Allocating memory for line.command [size: %zu]\n", line.size);
            #endif
            line.command = malloc(sizeof(struct command_t));
        } else {
            #ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "[PARSER] Reallocating memory for line.command [size: %zu]\n", line.size);
            #endif
            line.command = realloc(line.command, line.size * sizeof(struct command_t));
        }
        line.command[i].size=0;
        line.command[i].subcommand=NULL;
        for (j = 0, str2 = token1 ;; j++, str2 = NULL) {
            token2 = strtok_r(str2, del2, &saveptr2);
            if (token2 == NULL) break;
            line.command[i].size++;
            if (j == 0) {
                #ifdef DEBUG
                fprintf(stderr, "[PARSER] Allocating memory for line.command[%zu].subcommand [size: %zu]\n", i, line.command[i].size);
                #endif
                line.command[i].subcommand = malloc(sizeof(struct subcommand_t));
            } else {
                #ifdef DEBUG
                fprintf(stderr, "[PARSER] Reallocating memory for line.command[%zu].subcommand [size: %zu]\n", i, line.command[i].size);
                #endif
                line.command[i].subcommand = realloc(line.command[i].subcommand, line.command[i].size * sizeof(struct subcommand_t));
            }
            line.command[i].subcommand[j].size=0;
            line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument=NULL;
            for (k = 0, str3 = token2 ;; k++, str3 = NULL) {
                token3 = strtok_r(str3, del3, &saveptr3);
                if (token3 == NULL) break;
                line.command[i].subcommand[j].size++;
                if (k == 0) {
                    #ifdef DEBUG
                    fprintf(stderr, "[PARSER] Allocating memory for line.command[%zu].subcommand[%zu].argument [size: %zu]\n", i, j, line.command[i].subcommand[j].size);
                    #endif
                    line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument = malloc(sizeof(char *));
                } else {
                    #ifdef DEBUG
                    fprintf(stderr, "[PARSER] Reallocating memory for line.command[%zu].subcommand[%zu].argument [size: %zu]\n", i, j, line.command[i].subcommand[j].size);
                    #endif
                    line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument = realloc(line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument, (line.command[i].subcommand[j].size + 1) * sizeof(char *));
                }
                line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument[k] = malloc((strlen(token3)+1) * sizeof(char));
                memset(line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument[k], 0, strlen(token3)+1);
                strcpy(line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument[k], token3);
            }
            if (line.command[i].subcommand[j].size != 0) {
                #ifdef DEBUG
                fprintf(stderr, "[PARSER] Setting the NULL terminator for line.command[%zu].subcommand[%zu]\n", i, j);
                #endif
                line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument[line.command[i].subcommand[j].size] = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return line;
}

int main() {
    while (1) {
        prompt("$");
        char *buffer = reader(1024);
        struct line_t line = parser(buffer, ";", "|", " \t");
        executor(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that, in a university assignment, your goal isn't "be perfect", it's "do enough to prove that you're learning the course content." Similarly, in a job, your goal _still_ isn't perfection -- unless you're in a toxic work environment, in which case, find a new job before you burn out -- but satisfying whoever the users of the software will be. Your code will _never_ be perfect, be it because of lack of knowledge, time/budget constraints, other priorities, new things that didn't exist... And so on. Your goal is to write the best code that accomplishes the goals. You did that.

Comment: @NicHartley Hmmm... I see what you mean.

Comment: Here is a simplified version of the same shell https://github.com/xorz57/shell
It is memory-leak free

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You wrote a nice and simple shell. It works for very simple commands but fails on more complex ones (for details, see below). The code can be cleaned up in several places.

---

To make your code nicely readable by others, let an automatic formatter take care of the indentation and spacing. If you have GNU Indent available, use the following command line:

```
indent --k-and-r-style --no-tabs --line-length 200 --case-indentation 4 --braces-on-func-def-line shell.c
```

---

Instead of writing this every time:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
fprintf(stderr, "[READER] Allocating memory for buffer [size: %zu]\n", size);
#endif
```

you should define a macro DEBUG_PRINTF:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_PRINTF(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DEBUG_PRINTF(...) (void)0
#endif
```

Then you can just write:

```
DEBUG_PRINTF("[READER] Allocating memory for buffer [size: %zu]\n", size);
```

---

```
if (buffer == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Before exiting with an error code, you should print an error message. By convention, an empty output means success.

---

Enable all compiler warnings and fix them properly. For GCC, these are `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -O2`.

- Instead of `void prompt`, write `static void prompt`. This makes the function local to the current file and avoids conflicts just in case another file defines another function of the same name. (Also for the other functions.)
- Instead of `int main()`, write `int main(void)` to fix the "missing prototype" warning.
- Declare all read-only strings as `const char *` instead of `char *`. This affects the parameters to `prompt` and to `parser`.

---

Rename your functions. Function names are usually verbs. Your current names are `executor`, `parser`, etc. These are readable and understandable but still should be `execute` and `parse`.

For `reader`, this is more difficult since there is a system-provided function called `read`. Therefore it should be renamed to `read_line`.

---

Declare variables directly where you need them. Instead of:

```
char *buffer;
buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
```

just write:

```
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
```

Since `sizeof(char)` is defined to always be 1, leave it out:

```
char *buffer = malloc(size);
```

---

In the `executor` function, instead of repeating `line.command[i].subcommand[j]` everywhere, define a new variable:

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < line.command[i].size; ++j) {
    subcommand_t subcommand = line.command[i].subcommand[j];

    if (subcommand.size != 0) {
        // ...
```

---

The `parser` function currently parses the following command unexpectedly:

```
echo ";"
```

It outputs `"` but doesn't give any hint on why the semicolon and the second quotation mark were not echoed.

---

```
memset(line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument[k], 0, strlen(token3)+1);
strcpy(line.command[i].subcommand[j].argument[k], token3);
```

The `memset` is redundant and should be removed.

---

Any memory that you allocate with `malloc` or `realloc` must be freed after use with `free`.

---

When I press Ctrl+D in your shell, I get stuck in an endless loop. All other shells exit at that point (or instruct me that I must type `exit` instead of just Ctrl+D, which is really annoying).

To handle this situation, add error handling in the `reader` function and return from `main` if its return value is NULL.

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for your professional review. I will follow your recommendations when I have the time and post a follow-up question linked to this. As for the failing `echo` command, it's a shell built-in command that I have not implemented because it was not required for the assignment I was given. This could be implemented in the execute() function.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the output was checked against an automated grading system which is why I did not include warning messages.

Comment: @xorz57 Regarding the echo command: nothing I said was specific to the echo command, or whether the command is built-in or external. It was just about parsing of the commands.

Comment: Regarding the warnings: would your program pass the tests if you printed the warnings on `stderr`? The tests should allow this since it is common practice.

Comment: Our professor didn't allow us to print any extra  mesaages during the unit tests. Thats why i put the DEBUG flag.

Answer (score 5):

## Use of `_t`

You *may* want to reconsider use of `_t` endings in your type names.
In short, most of the standard type names use this, and the general practice is to not do so with user-defined types.

To quote POSIX:

> To allow implementors to provide their own types, all conforming applications are required to avoid symbols ending in "_t", which permits the implementor to provide additional types.

As a basic example:

```
typedef struct Subcommand {
    char **argument; // Array of arguments
    size_t size;     // Number of arguments
} Subcommand;
```

[There's also more information in this Stack Overflow question that may be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent)

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with the POSIX recommendation myself, though it does point out a very important limitation of C in general, i.e. the single namespace for `typedef`.